# Follow-up question to "A new combinatorial property for the character table of a finite group?" (from mathoverflow)

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, fusion-categories

Suppose I have a "character table" $\Lambda = (\lambda_{ij})$ of a purported tensor category $\mathcal{T}$ (perhaps some adjectives are needed); right now $\Lambda$ is just an $n \times n$ integer matrix with properties which I shall now list. As in the case of a finite group, we'll assume that the columns of $\Lambda$ are orthogonal and that for each index $1 \leq i \leq n$ there exists a positive rational value ${\frak{z}}(i)$ with
$\sum_i {\frak{z}}(i) = 1$ such that

\begin{equation} \sum_l \lambda_{i,l} \, \lambda_{j,l} \, {\frak{z}}(l) = \delta_{i,j} \end{equation}

We require that the entries of the first column $\lambda_{i,1}$ are strictly positive; they correspond to "dimensions" of the simple objects in our purported tensor category $\mathcal{T}$.
Furthermore let's assume that for any triple of rows $i, j, k$ we have non-negative integer *Kronecker coefficients* $g_{i,j}^k$ defined in the usual way by:

\begin{equation}
g_{i,j}^k \, := \, \sum_l \lambda_{i,l} \, \lambda_{j,l} \, \lambda_{k,l} \,
{\frak{z}}(l)
\end{equation}

Because $\Lambda$ is an integer matrix each Kronecker coefficient $g_{i,j}^k$ will be fully symmetric with respect to its three indices.
Let's require that $g_{i,j}^1 =\delta_{i,j}$ (which forces $g_{1,i}^j =  g_{i,1}^j =\delta_{i,j}$ by symmetry).
As described these Kroncker coefficients are structure constants for an n-dimensional, commutative, unital algebra $\Bbb{A}$: It has basis vectors $\Bbb{a}_1, \dots, \Bbb{a}_n$ with unit $1 = \Bbb{a}_1$ and product given by

\begin{equation}
\Bbb{a}_i \cdot \Bbb{a}_j \, = \,
\sum_k g_{i,j}^k \, \Bbb{a}_k \end{equation}

On top of all this, let's insist that $\Bbb{A}$ is associative (in case that doesn't come for free).

**Question:**
Given the circumstances which I've described, can it happen that Sebastien Palcoux's non-negativity condition for column triples of $\Lambda$ is violated (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344968/a-new-combinatorial-property-for-the-character-table-of-a-finite-group);
namely there exist columns $i, j, k$ such that

\begin{equation}
\sum_l { {\lambda_{l,i} \, \lambda_{l,j} \, \lambda_{l,k}} \over {\lambda_{l,1}} } < 0
\end{equation}

If this is possible, how does the failure of his non-negativity property restrict any purported tensor category $\mathcal{T}$ whose Grothendieck ring might coincide with $\Bbb{A}$? E.g. can we conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ can't be a fusion category ? If not, is there some weakening of the notion of fusion category which is appropriate ?

p.s. I'm sorry if the question is a bit vague; I'm still trying to get a lay of the land in the realm of Fusionism.

Comment: Short answer: it cannot be a **unitary** fusion category. More precisely, by Corollary 7.5 of [that paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12059v3), if a commutative fusion ring does not satisfy this non-negativity property on its character table, then it admits no unitary categorification. There exists also a more general property for the non-commutative fusion ring (See Proposition 7.3).

Comment: Dear Sebastien, Thank you; I'm looking over your paper now and I see the character table example on page 32; although the table involves roots of unity, no? However It seems that even in the case that I'm considering (where everything is integer) it's possible to find $\Lambda$-matrices which fail your condition; for example the $\Lambda$-matrix given here (note that the roles played by rows and columns are interchanged in this example) --- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303346/okada-character-table-for-n-6

Comment: To be specific it fails for the first, eleventh, and twelvth rows.